# how to test if a node is flagged in twig

Tags: 8

I would like to know how to test if a node is flagged.

In D7 : if ($ flag-> is_flagged ($ node-> nid)) But I discover D8 and I do not see how to do it with twig

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Write a function with hook preprocess_node in your custom module and set a custom variable isflagged ture or false
then check this variable in your twig file node is flagged or not 
like

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node().
 */
function yourModuleName_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node']; // Just in case you need it

  if($variables['node']->getType() == "yourNodeType") {
    // your code 
    if ($flag->is_flagged ($node->id())){
      $variables['isFlagged'] = true;
    }else{
      $variables['isFlagged'] = false;
    }

  }
}
```

now in your twig

```
{% if  isFlagged %}
  //do some thing
{% endif %}
```

hope this helps you

Comment: Upstreamed to flag: [Proprocess all target entities \[\#2925594\] \| Drupal\.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag/issues/2925594)